# Sum over N days excluding Weekends and Holidays

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below table

| AccountID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 07/02/2021 | 2000 |
| 123 | 07/09/2021 | 9000 |
| 123 | 07/15/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/20/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/28/2021 | 500 |

I am trying to create a test script to test data for just one month(July). I want to sum the amount over 5 days where 5 days does not count weekends and holidays. Since it is month of July the holiday falls on July 5th 2021(07/05/2021).

The output should look something like below

| AccountID | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 07/02/2021 | 11000 |
| 123 | 07/09/2021 | 9500 |
| 123 | 07/15/2021 | 1000 |
| 123 | 07/20/2021 | 500 |
| 123 | 07/28/2021 | 500 |

Below is the table create and data insert statements for reference :-

```
create table TRANSACTIONS (
  AccountID int,
  Date date,
  Amount int
)

insert into TRANSACTIONS values (123, '07/02/2021', 2000)
insert into TRANSACTIONS values (123, '07/09/2021', 9000)
insert into TRANSACTIONS values (123, '07/15/2021', 500)
insert into TRANSACTIONS values (123, '07/20/2021', 500)
insert into TRANSACTIONS values (123, '07/28/2021', 500)
```

I was able to create script that could sum over 5 days with skipping weekends(Saturday and Sunday). I am not able to think how can I skip the holiday on July 5th, 2021. I am fine with hardcoding it since this is just for testing purposes. The code '`DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7)`' skips Weekend and `'DATEADD(d, 6, h1.Date)'` here I am adding 6 and not 5 even the sum should be for over 5 days because after reading some articles I figured that in skipping weekends the last day is not inclusive so used 6 instead of 5. This code adds perfectly over 5 days skipping weekends

```
SELECT AccountId, Date,
(
  SELECT SUM(Amount) 
  FROM TRANSACTIONS h2
  WHERE 
    h1.AccountID = h2.AccountID and 
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7) and
    h2.Date between h1.Date AND DATEADD(d, 6, h1.Date)
) as SumAmount
FROM TRANSACTIONS h1
```

Comment: The only sane way to tackle this is to have a calendar table to represent holidays. The easiest approach is to store *every* date for the date range you're likely to need (eg 1970-2030) with the type of the date, perhaps and enum of `WORKDAY`, `WEEKEND`, `HOLIDAY` or whatever works. Depending on where you live, you may need to include a *region* column too (typically the country and/or state)

Comment: Like I mentioned I need to test just for month of July 2021 and there was just one holiday on July 5th 2021. For weekends I was able to figure out and use datepart(dw,date)) not in (1,7). Can you please also explain the logic if I have table with 5th July 2021 in it how can I count 5 days skipping this date? I have mentioned the query that I created where I am able to skip weekends while counting 5 days

Comment: By "holiday" do you mean any event with a mud depth greater than 0.5 [Smoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoot) on the Elbonian Calendar? Perhaps just bank holidays in New Hampshire, USA? Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: I meant Bank Holidays in USA like 5th July 2021. Since I am testing only July. I need a way to exclude this single day. For weekends I am already using DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7)

Comment: You need a complete calendar having every date, not just "holidays". A true and complete calendar table has so many uses. And let's not ignore the fact that weekends and holidays are not the only days where "work" is not done. Evacuations? Natural disasters? Loss of power? Infected network causing shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

The only sane way to tackle this is to have a calendar table to represent holidays. The easiest approach is to store every date for the date range you're likely to need (eg 1970-2030) with the type of the date, perhaps and enum of WORKDAY, WEEKEND, HOLIDAY or whatever works, eg

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR (
    Date DATE,
    Day_type varchar(16)
);
-- insert rows for dates you care about
```

Depending on where you live, you may need to include a region column too (typically the country and/or state).

With such a table, you join to it:

```
SELECT
    AccountId,
    DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.Date)/7)*7 + 7, 0) as Date,
    SUM(Amount)
FROM TRANSACTIONS t
JOIN CALENDAR c on t.Date = c.Date
    AND c.day_type = 'WORKDAY'
WHERE t.Date BETWEEN <your date range>
GROUP BY AccountId, DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.Date)/7)*7 + 7, 0)
```

Comment: I think jut for weekends using 'DATEPART(WEEKDAY, h2.Date) not in (1, 7)' is a very simple and easy method and deont require a table to be created. I am not sure how can we exclude holiday

Comment: @rohitpandey but it’s more code. With a calendar table you don’t need to code or remember such expressions

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do here 'DATEADD(DAY, (DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.Date)/7)*7 + 7, 0)'. Because for dates I want the day when first transaction was made? Like I mentioned in the desired output